# golang - Elem Vs Indirect in the reflect package

Tags: go

From the docs

```
func (v Value) Elem() Value
```

*Elem returns the value that the interface v contains or that the pointer v points to. It panics if v's Kind is not Interface or Ptr. It returns the zero Value if v is nil.*

```
func Indirect(v Value) Value
```

*Indirect returns the value that v points to. If v is a nil pointer, Indirect returns a zero Value. If v is not a pointer, Indirect returns v.*

So can I safely assume the following?

```
reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(someX)) === reflect.ValueOf(someX).Elem().
```

Is Indirect method just a convenience method for the right hand side of the above?

Comment: I have a follow up question to this one in case you know the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132517/golang-v-elem-vs-indirectv-when-passing-in-result-of-a-reflect-newtype

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If a `reflect.Value` is a pointer, then `v.Elem()` is equivalent to `reflect.Indirect(v)`.  If it is not a pointer, then they are not equivalent:

- If the value is an interface then `reflect.Indirect(v)` will return the same value, while `v.Elem()` will return the contained dynamic value.
- If the value is something else, then `v.Elem()` will panic.

The `reflect.Indirect` helper is intended for cases where you want to accept either a particular type, or a pointer to that type.  One example is the `database/sql` conversion routines: by using `reflect.Indirect`, it can use the same code paths to handle the various types and pointers to those types.

Comment: I have a follow up question to this one in case you know the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132517/golang-v-elem-vs-indirectv-when-passing-in-result-of-a-reflect-newtype