# v.Elem() Vs Indirect(v) when passing in result of a reflect.New(Type)

Tags: go, go-reflect

My question is related to this question here:

[golang - Elem Vs Indirect in the reflect package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318389/golang-elem-vs-indirect-in-the-reflect-package)

Basically it claims that the expression below is true if `someX` is a `reflect.Value` that contains a pointer

```
reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(someX)) === reflect.ValueOf(someX).Elem()
```

If that is the case, then why does my code below crash on the last line?

```
package main

import (
  "reflect"
  "log"
)

type Person struct {
  Name string

}

func main() {


newitem := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(Person{}).Type())

log.Println(reflect.TypeOf(newitem)) // shows reflect.Value
log.Println(newitem.Type().Kind()) // shows it is a ptr

log.Println(reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(newitem))) // this line does not cause panic
log.Println(reflect.ValueOf(newitem).Elem()) // this line causes panic

}
```

I've been having a hard time understanding the reflect package in Go, and it is likely I've misunderstood some fundamental aspects of the Go language as denoted in stack overflow questions I've been asking the past week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break down the following line:

```
log.Println(reflect.ValueOf(newitem).Elem())
```

The value `newItem` is a reflect.Value.  The expression `reflect.ValueOf(newItem)` returns a `reflect.Value` containing a `reflect.Value`.  Because the contained value is not a pointer or interface, the call to `Elem()` panics.

The following line does not panic because reflect.Indirect returns its argument if the argument is not a pointer type.

```
 log.Println(reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(newitem)))
```

The problem is that the application is wrapping reflect.Values with reflect.Values. Use the reflect.Value directly as in the following code:

```
log.Println(reflect.Indirect(newitem))
log.Println(newitem.Elem())
```

[Run it on the Playground!](https://play.golang.org/p/sZAa6uW4Cup)